# Python groupby behaves strangely

Tags: python, python-itertools

```
from itertools import groupby

source = [ [1,2], [1,3], [2, 1] ]
gby = groupby(source, lambda x: x[0])

print 'as list'
for key, vals in list(gby):
    print 'key {}'.format(key)
    for val in vals:
        print '  val {}'.format(val)

print

print 'as iter'
gby = groupby(source, lambda x: x[0])
for key, vals in gby:
    print 'key {}'.format(key)
    for val in vals:
        print '  val {}'.format(val)
```

Results:

```
as list
key 1
key 2
  val [2, 1]

as iter
key 1
  val [1, 2]
  val [1, 3]
key 2
  val [2, 1]
```

What is wrong with `list(gby)`? I would expect `list` to be pure function, how does it manage to corrupt internal state?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) makes a note about this:

> The returned group is itself an iterator that shares the underlying
>   iterable with groupby(). Because the source is shared, when the
>   groupby() object is advanced, the previous group is no longer visible.
>   So, if that data is needed later, it should be stored as a list:
>
> ```
> groups = []
> uniquekeys = []
> data = sorted(data, key=keyfunc)
> for k, g in groupby(data, keyfunc):
>     groups.append(list(g))      # Store group iterator as a list
>     uniquekeys.append(k)
> ```

You're exhausting the `groupby` object (by turning it into a list) prior to trying to iterate over the returned group iterators, so all the groups other than the last group are lost.

The reason for this is easier to figure out by looking at the Python implementation of the function:

```
class groupby(object):
    # [k for k, g in groupby('AAAABBBCCDAABBB')] --> A B C D A B
    # [list(g) for k, g in groupby('AAAABBBCCD')] --> AAAA BBB CC D
    def __init__(self, iterable, key=None):
        if key is None:
            key = lambda x: x
        self.keyfunc = key
        self.it = iter(iterable)
        self.tgtkey = self.currkey = self.currvalue = object()
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def next(self):
        while self.currkey == self.tgtkey:
            self.currvalue = next(self.it)
            self.currkey = self.keyfunc(self.currvalue)
        self.tgtkey = self.currkey
        return (self.currkey, self._grouper(self.tgtkey))
    def _grouper(self, tgtkey):  # This is the "group" iterator
        while self.currkey == tgtkey:  # self.currkey != tgtkey if you advance groupby and then try to use this object.
            yield self.currvalue
            self.currvalue = next(self.it)
            self.currkey = self.keyfunc(self.currvalue)
```

Calling `next(groupby)` advances the internal pointer to the underlying iterable (`self.currvalue`) to the next key, then returns the current key (`self.currkey`) and the `_grouper` iterator. `_grouper` takes the current key as an argument (called `tgtkey`), and will yield values (and recalculate `self.currkey`), until `self.currkey` is different than the `tgtkey`, meaning its returned all the values corresponding to the current key. So, if you advance `groupby` prior to using a `_grouper` object, `self.currkey` will *never* be equal to `tgtkey`, so the `_grouper` iterator will return nothing.

If for some reason you *do* need to store the `groupby` results in a list, you have to do it like this:

```
gby_list = []
for key, vals in gby:
    gby_list.append(key, list(vals))
```

Or:

```
gby_list = [key, list(vals) for key, vals in gby]
```

Comment: Could you explain why `vals` are not printed the first time around though? I mean in the first iteration of the "as list" code snippet.

Comment: how would the OP'S code look to incorporate this?

Comment: The `groupby`  iterator yields two things: a `key`, and a `group` iterator. The `group` iterator shares the underlying iterable with the `groupby` iterator. That means when you advance the `groupby` iterator, the `group` iterator is now useless (see my edit for an illustration of why). So, in your first loop, you're calling `list(gby)`. That will iterate over the entire `groupby` object, and store the contents in a list. That means that all the `group` iterators returned, other than the last one, are useless.

Comment: IOW, *always* treat `groupby` as an iterator, and consume the `grouper` objects immediately as they are yielded by `groupby`.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I added example code to show how to store the `groupby` iterator as a list, but in most cases you'd probably just want to actually use it as an iterator.

Comment: Reeeeally strange design decision. I think iterator should not have state. Coming from C# where all IEnumerables don't have state this is unexpected.